# React Redux how to dispatch async actions and update state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, dispatch, redux-thunk

I try to deal with ajax data in my learning react,redux project and I have no idea how to dispatch an action and set the state inside a component

here is my component

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import Upload from './Upload';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as profileActions from '../../../actions/profileActions';


class Profile extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        //getProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        //profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            profile:{
                username: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
        this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this)
    }

    onUpdate(event) {
        alert()
    }

    componentWillMount() {
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }


    render() {

        const {profile} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        profile: state.default.profile,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(profileActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

I create the store as it follows

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import reducers from '../reducers'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const middleware = [ thunk ];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middleware.push(createLogger());
}

middleware.push(routerMiddleware(browserHistory));

// Add the reducer to your store on the `routing` key
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        reducers,
        routing: routerReducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),

)

export default store;
```

reducer

```
export const RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE = 'RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE'

const profileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE':
            return action.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default profileReducer;
```

actions

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import Api from '../middleware/Api';

export function getProfile() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLoadingProfileState()); // Show a loading spinner
        Api.getAll('profile').then(profile => {
            dispatch(doneFetchingProfile(profile));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
        /*Api.fetch(`profile`, (response) => {
            console.log(response)
            dispatch(doneFetchingBook()); // Hide loading spinner
            if(response.status == 200){
                dispatch(setProfile(response.json)); // Use a normal function to set the received state
            }else {
                dispatch(error)
            }
        }) */
    }
}

function setProfile(data) {
    return {type: types.SET_PROFILE, data: data}
    //return { type: types.SET_PROFILE, data: data };
}


function setLoadingProfileState() {
    return {type: types.SHOW_SPINNER}
}

function doneFetchingProfile(data) {
    console.log(data)
    return {
        type: types.HIDE_SPINNER,
        profile: data
    }
}

function error() {
    return {type: types.SHOW_ERROR}
}
```

but I have no idea how would I dispatch action and update the state after getProfile action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only dispatch your event `RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE` right after dispatching `doneFetchingProfile`, or simply listen `RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE` and hide spinner on reducing it.

```
 Api.getAll('profile').then(profile => {
    dispatch(doneFetchingProfile(profile));
    dispatch(resoloveGetProfile(profile));
 })
```

Actually you r doing everything right - so I didn't understand what is your question is, so if you meant something else - let me know, I`ll try to describe you.

### About  dispatch(resoloveGetProfile(profile));

There you dispatch action, which will update your state, simple as you do with some static state, I saw that you already have `setProfile` action, so you can change that line, to call your existed function.

```
dispatch(setProfile(profile))
```

Than you need to reduce your state in this action

```
case 'SET_PROFILE' : (action, state) => {...state, profile: action.data}
```

Than your state will change and your components will update. Note that your 'get profile method' better to call from `componentDidMount` to avoid freezing at rendering because of performing web request.

Comment: thanks for feedback! Can you please explain bit  this part `dispatch(resoloveGetProfile(profile));`. Am I going to make a new function and what I do there?

Comment: Update your question